# Security digit java multiplication

Tags: java

Say the user inputs an int `123214`

I have managed to separate the digits however how can i multiply the digits by one and other.

E.g. I want `1*2*3*2*1*4`

I put all the single digits into an array but I can't multiply them by one and other as I want.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
int res = 1;
for (char c : "123214".toCharArray()) {
    res *= (c - '0');
}
```

This works because binary codes of digits are consecutive. By subtracting the code of zero character `'0'` you obtain the value of the digit as an integer number from zero to nine, inclusive.

Here is a link to [this snippet on ideone](http://ideone.com/ULZ8q). It prints `48`.

Comment: but what if only non zero integers are multiplied

Comment: @fosho Add an `if` condition to check that `c != '0'` before multiplying.

Comment: @fosho the multiplication. `if (c != '0') res *= (c - '0');`

Comment: @fosho I would recommend looking into ASCII code and see, what dasblinkenlight did in his example. Once you realized how the relationship between a `char` and its numerical representation works, you will understand his example much better.